# JavaScript scopes and object-orientation

Tags: javascript, scope

What's wrong with this—how come the variable `foo` isn't defined from within `onModified()` of a `Document` object?

```
function Document() {

    var foo = "dfsadf";

    this.onModified = function() {
        alert(foo);
    };

}

// Does not alert; "foo" doesn't resolve
new Document().onModified();
```

I'd like to have public methods on `Document` that reference variables that are somehow private to `Document`.

Comment: Are you sure? That should alert `'dfsadf'`.

Comment: you are testing on Firefox, aren't you? :)

Comment: what happens when you name your constructor something besides Document ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Document` function is clashing with the `Document` constructor from the DOM.

```
document instanceof Document; // true
```

As with any [*host-object*](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#hostObject) its behavior completely depends on the *host environment*, and they often can give you unexpected results.

As far I've tested, on Firefox you are not able to *replace its value*, therefore I would recommend you to either, *rename your function*, or, *declare it on other scope*.